# Deploy .Net Core MVC app w/ class library to Ubuntu 16.04:

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I wanted to build a simple .net core MVC app with a single class library for data access, to get an idea of what it takes to build/deploy/run Core on Linux. Not nearly as simple as I had hoped!

**EDIT**: Here's a copy of the solution, if anyone is interested:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/kilonova-public/code/CoreCrossPlatform.zip

I threw together a VirtualBox VM w/ Ubuntu Server 16.04 and installed dotnet core per these instructions:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu

I installed all the latest, necessary bits on the host (Win10) for VS 2015 and created a solution with an MVC app and single class library called "DataAccess". It's EF Core talking to MySQL using their latest core provider. It all runs flawlessly on the Win10 host when I run/debug it. Pulls up data and looks great.

"dotnet --version" on both the host and the VM gives me:

> 1.0.0-preview2-003121

However, when I deploy it to the Ubuntu VM, I get the following error on the class library dependency:

```
Project corecrossplatform (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because the version or bitness of the CLI changed since the last build
Compiling corecrossplatform for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
/opt/dotnet/corecrossplatform/project.json(24,23): error NU1002: The dependency DataAccess  does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

Compilation failed.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:00.0187782
```

This happens whether I run "dotnet restore" or "dotnet run". To be perfectly honest, I'm not even sure I'm deploying this thing correctly. Documentation is spotty and I'm making some guesses. I copied everything from the project folder "src\CoreCrossPlatform" (contains bin, Program.cs, appsettings.json, etc.) onto the VM and this is where I'm executing the "dotnet" commands from, in the VM.

The DataAccess .json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
        "MySql.Data.Core": "7.0.4-IR-191",
        "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.4-IR-191",
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
    },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

The MVC project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "DataAccess": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Something to note: When I run the sample project using "dotnet new" and restore, run vis the tutorial link above, it runs fine.

What am I missing? Another side question: What's the best way to publish this type of app to a Linux box? Am I even close on that part?

Thanks much.

**EDIT**: While kicking this dead horse all afternoon, I compared some notes I found online, related to this "NU1002" error, and the sample project "dotnet new" generates. I tried changing the "framework" section of both project.json files (MVC and classlib) to the following, with no success...same error:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                "type": "platform",
                "version": "1.0.0"
            }
        },
        "imports": [
            "dnxcore50",
            "dotnet5.6",
            "portable-net45+win8"
        ]
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Much thanks to goaty: As he pointed out in the comments, copying over the entire solution and building it, results in a successful build. However, I cannot run it without an error. It doesn't seem to restore the MySQL EF Core dependency:

```
Project CoreCrossPlatformFlat (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because the version or bitness of the CLI changed since the last build
Compiling CoreCrossPlatformFlat for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
/opt/dotnet/corecrossplatform/src/CoreCrossPlatformFlat/project.json(25,52): error NU1001: The dependency MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore >= 7.0.4-IR-191 could not be resolved.

Compilation failed.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Comment: I just checked out your solution. It looks like in your src/CoreCrossPlatform folder there's only the web project. The class library is not there ?

Comment: @goaty - Really weird. Might not have zipped at the root? Re-upped a fresh copy. Thanks.

Comment: your new upload says Access denied :)

Comment: @goaty - Ha! Wow. Made public, please try again.

Comment: Also of note: There's a "SQL" folder in the DataAccess project. I threw a script in there for creating and seeding a mysql db and table, to test with.

Comment: I can restore and compile your project with no problem. According to you, you copied the "src\CoreCrossPlatform" folder to the Linux VM. Why only that folder and not the whole project? The DataAccess project does not exist in that folder which leads to compile failure.

Comment: @goaty - Man, I thought I had tried that. You're right, it builds this way. That just downright makes sense! :) However, it won't run. It doesn't want to restore the MySQL dependency: "error NU1001: The dependency MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore >= 7.0.4-IR-191 could not be resolved". Interesting to note: I created a new version of this solution with all of the stuff in DataAccess included into the web project, so I could get rid of the class lib dependency. I get the same NU1001 error in that project.

Comment: @goaty - Yo solved my initial problem. Go ahead and post as answer if you'd like me to mark it, so you get credit. Going to post new problem as a new question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: thanks :-) According to this [link](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/mysql/) EF core provider for Mysql might not be ready yet. But it should work once released :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataAccess` library exists outside of your src/ directory. Therefore the web project could not find the reference.
I recommend this structure

```
src/
|---DataAccess/
|---CoreCrossPlatform/
```

Hope that helps :)